# AWS Babelfish with Postgres is throwing sporadic error

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, babelfish

we are using AWS Babelfish with Postgres enabled DB, ideally it's a Postgres DB. There are frequent errors related to ***could not open relation***. The same SP executes fine sometimes and same one fails with error sporadically if not more frequently. I have found a article[https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/12791.1310599941%40sss.pgh.pa.us] which discuss about the error, but it doesn't point the exact issue. And other articles doesn't help me understand the pattern of the error. I have added ***.dbo*** to all the tables as one of the possible fix and dropped all the temp tables at end of the SP as well.

```
Level 16, State 1, Line 4
could not open relation with OID 54505
```

Comment: What does the stored procedure do? The referenced postgresql.org talks about a timing issue with accessing system catalog tables like pg_class and pg_relation_size while temporary tables are being dropped. Does your SP do that kind of examination of all the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please always include the Babelfish version (SELECT CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('BabelfishVersion') AS VARCHAR) ). The upcoming v.2.4.0 had a bug fixed which raised this error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do we know any timelines, we can expect this version to be live?

Comment: Also, do you see this bug was introduced in v2.3 version only?

Comment: Without a reproduction it is not possible to conclusively say that your issue will be fixed in v.2.4.0, but there was a bug fix in 2.4.0 for an issue with this error message. v.2.4.0 is being rolled out "very soon". I suggest checking Aurora/PG in your favorite region every few days from now on.